# Performance drop dramatically when levels get deeper in graph travelsal

Tags: arangodb

I've been working on a config management system using arangodb which collect config data for some common software and stream to a program which will generate the relationship among those softwares based on some pre-defined rules and then save the relations into arangodb. After the relations established, I provides APIs to query the data. One important query is to generate the topology of these softwares. I use graph traversal to generate the topology with following AQL:

```
for n in nginx for v,e,p in 0..4 outbound n forward, dispatch, route,INBOUND deployto, referto,monitoron filter @domain in p.edges[0].server_name return {id: v._id, type: v.ci_type}
```

which can generate the following topology:
[software relation topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeC5c.png)

Which looks fine. However, It takes around 10 seconds to finish the query which is not acceptable because the volume is not very large. I checked all the collections and the largest collection, the "forward" edge collection only has around 28000 documents. So I did some tests:
I changed depth from 0..4 to 0..2 and it only takes 0.3 second to finish the query
I changed depth from 0..4 to 0..3, it takes around 3 seconds
for 0..4, it takes around 10 seconds
Since there is a server_name property on the "forward" edge, so I add a hash index(server_name[*]) but it seems arangodb doesn't use the index from the explain execute plan
Any tips I can optimize the query? and why the index can't be used in this case?

Hope someone can help me out with this. Thanks in advance,

Comment: I've seen queries slow down like this too, but the cause of the slowness can sometimes be just the volume of data being returned. Have you tried to measure the size of the response when returning the data for 0..2 versus 0..4? Wondering if there are any surprises in there around the size of the response.

Comment: Actually, the return data is in a small set. It is a vector of around 400 elements which has two-field hashmap for 0..4.

Answer (score 2):

First of all i have tried your query and i could see that for some reason the:

```
filter @domain in p.edges[0].server_name
```

Is not optimized correctly. This seems to be an internal issue with the optimization rule not being good enough, i will take a detailed look into this and try to make sure that it works as expected.
For this reason it will not yet be able to use a different index for this case, and will not do short-circuit to abort search on level 1 correctly.
I am very sorry for the inconvenience, as the way you did it should be the correct one.

To have a quick workaround for now you could split the first part of the query in a separate step:

This is the fast version of my modified query (which will not include the nginx, see slower version)

```
FOR n IN nginx
  FOR forwarded, e IN 1 OUTBOUND forward
    FILTER @domain IN e.server_name
    /* At this point we only have the relevant first depth vertices*/
    FOR v IN 0..3 OUTBOUND forward, dispatch, route, INBOUND deployto, referto, monitoron
      RETURN {id: v._id, type: v.ci_type}
```

This is a slightly slower version of my modified query (saving your output format, and i think it will be faster than the one your are working with)

```
FOR tmp IN(
  FOR n IN nginx
    FOR forwarded, e IN 1 OUTBOUND forward
      FILTER @domain IN e.server_name
      /* At this point we only have the relevant first depth vertices*/
      RETURN APPEND([{id: n._id, type: n.ci_type}],(
       FOR v IN 0..3 OUTBOUND forward, dispatch, route, INBOUND deployto, referto, monitoron
       RETURN {id: v._id, type: v.ci_type}
      )
  )[**]
RETURN tmp
```

In i can give some general advise:

1. (This will work after we fixed the optimizer) Usage of the index: ArangoDB uses statistics/assumptions of the index selectivity (how good it is to find the data) to decide which index is better. In your case it may assume that the edge-index is better than your hash-index. You could try to create a combined hash_index on ["_from", "server_name[*]"] which is more likely to have a better estimate than the EdgeIndex and could be used.
2. In the example you have given i can see that there is a "large" right part starting at the apppkg node. In the query this right part an be reached in two ways:
   a) nginx -> tomcat <- apppkg
   b) nginx -> varnish -> lvs -> tomcat <- apppkg
   This means the query could walk through the subtree starting at apppkg multiple times (once for every path leading there). With the query depth of 4 and only this topology it does not happen, but if there are shorter paths this may also be an issue. If i am not mistaken than you are only interested in the distinct vertices in the graph and the path is not important right? If so you can add OPTIONS to the query that will make sure that no vertex (and dependent subtree) is analysed twice. The modified query would look like this:

   for n in nginx
     for v,e,p in 0..4 outbound n forward, dispatch, route, INBOUND deployto, referto, monitoron
     OPTIONS {bfs: true, uniqueVertices: "global"}
       filter @domain in p.edges[0].server_name
       return {id: v._id, type: v.ci_type}

the change i made is that i add options to the traversal:
  bfs: true => Means we do a breadth-first-search instead of a depth-first-search, we only need this to make the result deterministic and make sure that all vertices with a path of depth 4 will be reached correctly
  uniqueVertices: "global" => Means whenever a vertex is found in one traversal (so in your case for every nginx separately) it is flagged and will not be looked at again.

If you need the list of all distinct edges as well you should use `uniqueEdges: "global"` instead of `uniqueVertices: "global"` which will make this uniqueness check on edge level.

Comment: ,Thanks for your so informative response and helpful advices. The #1 suggestion is exactly what I'm trying to test next and I'm looking forward to your update for the query optimizer.

Comment: Hi,@mchacki,I applied the #2 and the time drop to 2 seconds. It's great but I'd like it can finish within 1 second. So can I ask what's the progress about #1? Can I use the index of some properties of an edge now?